# Is it possible to debug XCFramework code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework

Part of an app I've worked on is distributed as XCFramework which is built with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts s:w: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        s) scheme=${OPTARG};;
        w) workspace="-workspace ${OPTARG}.xcworkspace";;
    esac
done

if [ -z "$scheme" ]
then
      echo "$(basename $BASH_SOURCE) -- build XCFramework"
      echo ""
      echo "$(basename $BASH_SOURCE) -s scheme-name [ -w workspace0-name ]"
      echo ""
      echo "Run this script from the top-level directory of your framework."
      echo "The build result will be here: archives/<scheme-name>.xcframework"
      exit
fi

rm -rf archives/$scheme.xcframework

xcodebuild archive \
           $workspace \
           -scheme $scheme \
           -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
           -archivePath "archives/$scheme-Simulator" \
           SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
           BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

xcodebuild archive \
           $workspace \
           -scheme $scheme \
           -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
           -archivePath "archives/$scheme" \
           SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
           BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

cp -r archives/$scheme-Simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/. archives/simulator
cp -r archives/$scheme.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/. archives/ios

function GetUUID() {
    local arch=$1
    local binary=$2
    local dwarfdump_result=$(dwarfdump -u ${binary})
    local regex="UUID: (.*) \((.*)\)"
    if [[ $dwarfdump_result =~ $regex ]]; then
        local result_uuid="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        local result_arch="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        if [ "$result_arch" == "$arch" ]; then
            echo $result_uuid
        fi
    fi
}

BCSYMBOLMAP_UUID=$(GetUUID "arm64" "archives/$scheme.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/$scheme.framework/$scheme")

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
           -framework archives/ios/$scheme.framework \
           -debug-symbols ${PWD}/archives/$scheme.xcarchive/dSYMs/$scheme.framework.dSYM \
           -debug-symbols "${PWD}/archives/$scheme.xcarchive/BCSymbolMaps/${BCSYMBOLMAP_UUID}.bcsymbolmap" \
           -framework archives/simulator/$scheme.framework \
           -debug-symbols ${PWD}/archives/$scheme-Simulator.xcarchive/dSYMs/$scheme.framework.dSYM \
           -output archives/$scheme.xcframework

cd archives
rm -rf $scheme-Simulator.xcarchive $scheme.xcarchive ios simulator
```

The output `<my-framework>.xcframework` directory is then copy-pasted to the app.

What needs to be done to allow/enable debugging functions that are part of the framework, while running the app?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677716
I think debugging via source code is not possible in the normal way.. The alternative way is to expose your framework via SPM and consume via SPM only for debug cases such that you can debug in source code